# How to prove that $P (X ≥ k) = (1 - p)^k$? Can I start with $P(X≥k)=1−P(X<k)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

### **The exercise says:**

> Let $X$ ~ $G (p)$. Prove that $P (X ≥ k) = (1 - p)^k$, with $k ∈ N$.

### **My try to demonstrate it:**

- $P (X ≥ k) = 1-P(X<k)$
- $P (X+1 ≥ k+1) = 1-P(X+1<k+1) = 1-P(X⩽k)$
- $P (X+1 ≥ k+1) = 1-((1-p)^kp)$
- $P (X+1-1 ≥ k+1-1) = 1-(((1-p)^kp)-1)$
- $P (X ≥ k) = 1-(((1-p)^kp)-1)$

Comment: If you think of $X+1$ as the first time in a sequence of coin tosses that the coin lands heads (with probability of landing heads $p$ on each toss), then $X+1\geq k+1$ if and only if the first $k$ tosses landed tails, which happens with probability...

Comment: I am sorry. But I did not quite understand your analogy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\bbox[0.5ex]{X\sim\mathcal{Geo}_0(p)}$ means $X$ is a count of failures before a success in an indefinite sequence of independent Bernoulli trials with identical success rate $p$.

$\bbox[0.5ex]{\mathsf P(X\geq k)\quad [k\in\Bbb N]}$ is then the probability for the first success occurring after at least $k$ consecutive failures.   Which is simply the probability for obtaining $k$ consecutive failures.

$$\mathsf P(X\geq k)=(1-p)^k$$

Of course you can show this by using $\bbox[0.5ex]{\mathsf P(X=k)~=~(1-p)^kp}$ (but *why* is that so)?

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X\geq k) &= \sum_{j=k}^\infty (1-p)^j p
\\ & = (1-p)^kp\sum_{j=k}^\infty (1-p)^{j-k}
\\ &  \vdots
\end{align}$$

Comment: The first explanation is the demonstration itself? Or should I do something else?

Comment: @CarlosFrostte The first should suffice but, just in case, you can complete the second.  (Hint: It is beginning to look a lot like a Geometric Series.)